# Authentication: encode custom claims in JWT

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I have the following problem:

- I have a NodeJS Server
- I don't want to handle Authentication my self (I don't want to have to store userpasswords and all that)
- I want to give the User a custom JWT and Refreshtoken where I encode some custom values on my nodejs server

The authentication flow is as follows: User sends request to NodeJS server => sends request to auth-server => sends back Authentication result => nodejs server gets some data from DB for user => encodes that data to JWT => sends the User the JWT back

So basically my question is, if there are any best practices for this, how to manage a refresh token, shall I issue my own refresh token or should I forward the RefreshToken from the auth service...

Or am I on the complete wrong path?

Any help, reading direction or discussion is very appreciated!

Comment: You can't alter a JWT, you can only create a new one from scratch (assuming you have the private key).

Comment: yes thats clear. I just wanted to know if there is any best practise for doing this. thinking of managing my own key (cause my server is the only authority).